# Unit Testing WCF Service using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, wcf, moq

I have been teaching myself how to unit test various parts of my application. I am trying to do a unit test of my UserService. I seem to be getting the following error:
[image: User Service Error]

I am not sure what the error means. Could someone explain what is going on? I know the service itself works already I tested it separately. I have never created unit tests before so if someone could please give me a detailed explanation as to why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

**User Service Test**

```
public class UserServiceTest
{
    public readonly IUserService MockUserService;


    public List<UserDTO> userDTOList = new List<UserDTO>
    {
        new UserDTO(new User{UserId = 1, FirstName = "Eric"}),
        new UserDTO(new User{UserId = 1, FirstName = "Dave"}),
        new UserDTO(new User{UserId = 1, FirstName = "Jim"})

    };

    public UserServiceTest()
    {
        Mock<IUserService> mockUserService = new Mock<IUserService>();

        mockUserService.Setup(mr => mr.GetAllUsers()).Returns(userDTOList);
        this.MockUserService = mockUserService.Object;

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestServiceGetUsers()
    {
        List<UserDTO> testUserList = this.MockUserService.GetAllUsers();

        Assert.IsNotNull(testUserList);
        Assert.AreEqual(userDTOList, testUserList);
    }
}
```

**WCF Interface**

```
 [ServiceContract]
public interface IUserService
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<UserDTO> GetAllUsers();

}

[DataContract]

public class UserDTO
{
    public UserDTO(User user)
    {
        this.FirstName = user.FirstName;
        this.LastName = user.LastName;
        this.NumberOfItemsSold = user.NumberOfItemsSold;
        this.UserId = user.UserId;
        this.UserName = user.UserName;

    }

    [DataMember]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int NumberOfItemsSold { get; set; }
}
```

**WCF Interface implementation**

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    public List<UserDTO> GetAllUsers()
    {
        using (UnitOfWork work = new UnitOfWork(new ProductContext()))
        {

            return work.Users.GetAll().Select(a => new UserDTO(a)).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit after suggestion from Mel Gerats**

Okay so I figured I would place the updated code for my unit test that actually tests the service now. Here it is! Thanks again for the help.

```
[TestClass]
public class UserServiceTest
{

    public List<UserDTO> userDTOList = new List<UserDTO>
    {
        new UserDTO(new User{UserId = 1, FirstName = "Eric"}),
        new UserDTO(new User{UserId = 2, FirstName = "Dave"}),
        new UserDTO(new User{UserId = 3, FirstName = "Jim"})

    };

    public IEnumerable<User> users = new List<User>
    {
        new User{UserId = 1, FirstName = "Eric"},
        new User{UserId = 2, FirstName = "Dave"},
        new User{UserId = 3, FirstName = "Jim"}
    };

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestServiceGetUsers()
    {
        //Setup
        var unitOfWorkMock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        unitOfWorkMock.Setup(m => m.Users.GetAll()).Returns(users);

        var serviceUnderTest = new UserService(unitOfWorkMock.Object);



        var result = serviceUnderTest.GetAllUsers();

        Assert.IsNotNull(result);

        Assert.AreEqual(userDTOList.Count, result.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(userDTOList[0].FirstName, result[0].FirstName);
        Assert.AreEqual(userDTOList[1].FirstName, result[1].FirstName);
    }
}
```

For some reason I could not directly test if the two lists were equal. I think it is because the Capacity of the lists were different on my lists. So I opted for testing each position in the list.

Comment: Are you referencing `System.ServiceModel` in your test project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing a reference to `System.ServiceModel`

But your test doesn't actually test anything, except maybe that mocking works, as you are only calling the mocked method on the mock.

The goal of mocking is to test your class under test while mocking the dependencies. If your UserService had a dependency on a UserRepository for example, you would mock the repository in order to test the UserService.

The following example illustrates this:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private IUserRepository _userRepository;
    private IUserNotification _userNotification;

    public UserService(IUserRepository userRepository, IUserNotification userNotification)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
        _userNotification = userNotification;   
    }

    public void NotifyInactiveUsers(DateTime activeBefore)
    {
        var users = _userRepository.GetAllUsers();
        foreach(var user in users)
        {
            if(user.LastActivityDate > DateTime.Now)
            {
                _userNotification.SendRemovalNotification(user)
                _userRepository.MarkUserForRemoval(user)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The UserService provides an operation to notify all users that are inactive since a given date.

```
public void TestUserService_NotifyInactiveUsers_BeforeActivityDate()
{
    var userRepository = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
    var userNotification = new Mock<IUserNotification>();
    var userService = new UserService(userRepository.Object, userNotification.Object);

    var testUser = new User { LastActivityDate = DateTime.Now}
    userRepository.Setup(r => r.GetAllUsers()).Returns(Enumerable.Repeat(testUser, 1));

    userService.NotifyInactiveUsers(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1));

    userNotification.Verify(n => n.SendRemovalNotification(It.IsAny<User>), Times.Never);
}
```

The test sets up the UserRepository to return one user that was active today.
It then calls the operation on the UserService, and verifies that SendRemovalNotification was never called. This tests whether or not the logic to determine if a user is inactive is indeed correct.

Comment: I see. That did seem kind of weird to me. I found that example online. Could you give me an example on how to do this? I do actually have a UserRepository this service is calling. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I've added an example

Comment: You forgot to include an interface in the constructor. So if I wanted to test the getallusers function of my service I would call userservice.getallusers() and verify that it equals the testUser. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I would also have to mock up my unitofwork interface...which not sure how go do that with the context being passed in.